# What path do images get saved to when using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in simulator?

Tags: xcode, image, swift, ios8

I have an app where I'm using

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

to save images that the app creates. I'd like to examine these images on my computer as they're saved when they app runs on the simulator, but I can't find where these images are stored on the computer. Would love any input.

Comment: just store it also at your app documents folder and keep the url

Comment: define "also"? I have no idea where the originals are, that's the issue i'm having

Comment: let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL

Comment: let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image001.jpg")

Comment: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0).writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this:

let imageData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedimage))
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
 var docs: String = paths[0] as! String
let fullPath = docs.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yourNameImg.png")
let result = imageData.writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
print(fullPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Cmd-Shift-H (or from the Simulator menu -> Hardware -> Home) to go to the Home screen in your Simulator.

And operate the Simulator like a real device: open Photo app, and you can see the images you save via `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` in there.